# Could not resolve com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision:0.13.0

Tags: android

> I followed this link https://vision.mapbox.com/install/ but got always Could not resolve com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision:0.13.0.

Comment: Follow the [Sample](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-vision-android)  you probably missed something in gradle configuration.

Comment: have you managed to solve this?